# ScrollView is not starting from beginning nor reaching end of list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mobile-development

I have an IOS app, where I have 2 lists, that I am displaying on the screen, basically a vertical scrollview, inside of it a horizontal scrollview with 2 lists:

Vertical ScrollView:

- Horizontal ScrollView:

  1. SampleProfileView
  2. SampleProfileViewB

Component 1:

```
@ViewBuilder
func SampleProfileView() -> some View{
    var arrayData: [Int] = Array(1…50);
    LazyVStack{
        Text("About")
            .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Bold", size: 25))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        VStack{
            ForEach(arrayData, id: \.self){item in
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                    //                        .frame(height: 100)
                    
                    Text("\(item)")
                        .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Bold", size: 30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is Component 2:

```
@ViewBuilder
func SampleProfileViewB() -> some View{
    var arrayData: [Int] = Array(1…50);
    LazyVStack{
        Text("About")
            .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Bold", size: 25))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        VStack{
            ForEach(arrayData, id: \.self){item in
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                    //                        .frame(height: 100)
                    
                    Text("\(item)")
                        .font(.custom("PlayfairDisplay-Bold", size: 30))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

I am using both components in the following Main View component:

```
    NavigationStack{
        ScrollView(.vertical){
            LazyVStack{
                TopProfileHeaderView()
                
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal){
                    LazyHStack{
                        
                        SampleProfileView()
                            .id(0)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                        
                        
                        SampleProfileViewB()
                            .id(1)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                       
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                .scrollIndicators(.visible)
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

**Image 1:** As you can see in the first image, at the top, **it does not start from the beginning of the list (ie. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), it does not scroll up to the start of the list.**

**Image 2:** In the second image, you can see that when I scroll, **it does not reach the end of the list** (last number is 50 in the list).

Screenshots:

[image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtKwh.png)
[image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooGHa.png)

**My Question:**

My question is, what is preventing the list from being full height and reaching the first item in the list and the last item in the list.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Appreciate your feedback.
Thanks.

Comment: Hm, when I add this to an empty project and run it on an iOS 17 simulator, the scroll views start at the top for me. Also I can scroll down to 50 in both lists. What iOS version are you having the issue with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

You need to define the alignment the `LazyHStack` needs to use.
If the two different sections have a different height, then you need to tell SwiftUI how to align those two views within your `LazyHStack`. By default it's using `.center`. Meaning one of the two different views gets misaligned and that might lead to two issues.

To fix this, use:

```
LazyHStack(alignment: .top) { ... }
```

Then both the smaller and the taller view will align on the top and that issue will be fixed.

However that will still not fix the issue #2. Also I'm not sure whether there is a solution for the second problem to be honest.